# JavaScript not receiving JSON data from PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have been doing a mock up for a train departure Board. Mainly to refresh and learn how to do stuff. I'm requesting the data from Darwin with SOAP. I have no issues when I fixed the station in my file i.e. $response = $OpenLDBWS->GetDepBoardWithDetails(15,"BHM");
WIth that, I have the information in json and then I show it as a departure board.
The issues comes when I create a dropdown menu to select the station and then send that into my file. i.e $response = $OpenLDBWS->GetDepBoardWithDetails(15,$train_sta); where $train_sta is the selected station.

I can see the json data but my js file doesn't send the data anymore. Is like somehow my data is being errased.

Edit: I have try now handling the submit event with $('form').submit(function() in my js. I can confirm that the form is being submitted as I have used the same function on my selector code. Might be using form action and method in the wrong file. I don't seem to handle the event with js.

```
var timeout = 60;

function startTime() 
{
    var time = new Date();
    var clock = time.toLocaleString('en-UK', {timeZone: "Europe/London", hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', hour12: false});
    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = clock;     
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) 
{
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  
  return i;
}

/*
$('#selectTrainStations').change(function() {
  // Get the selected value
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("Document ready");

*/


$(document).ready(function(){

    console.log("Document ready");

    $('form').submit(function() {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting normally
      var selectedValue = $('#train_stations :selected').val();
      console.log("Selected Station: ", selectedValue); 



      $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxfile_selector.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            //response = JSON.parse(response)
            console.log("Response data: ", response);
            //console.log(response);
            //var data = JSON.stringify(response);//JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)); //JSON.parse
            //console.log(data);
            //subsequentCallingPoints.callingPointList[0].callingPoint[0].locationName
            //var trainData = JSON.parse(data);
            //var trainData = response.GetStationBoardResult.trainServices.service;
            //var selectedStation = selectedStation;
            //console.log(selectedStation);
            var trainData = response.train;

            console.log("Train Data: ",trainData);

            $("#trainTable").html('');
            var index;

            for (index = 0; index < trainData.length; ++index){
                //console.log(trainData[index]);
                var borderStyle = '';
                var carriageInfo = '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;';
                if (index != (trainData.length-1)){
                    borderStyle = 'border-bottom: 1px solid white;';
                }
                if (trainData[index]['carriages'] != '-'){
                    carriageInfo = ', this train has ' + trainData[index].carriages + ' carriages';
                }
                var html = `
                <!---TRAIN ROW-->
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1">` + trainData[index].schd + `</div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 TrainDestination">` + trainData[index].destination +`</div>
                <div class="col-sm-1 text-md-center">` + trainData[index].platform + `</div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 text-md-center">` + trainData[index].etd + `</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row no-gutters" style="padding-left: 94px;` + borderStyle + `">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-1 trainfont">Callling at:</div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 trainfont">
                <marquee>` + trainData[index].callingPointsString + `</marquee>
                </div>
                <span class="trainfont">Operated by ` + trainData[index].toc + ``+
                carriageInfo +` </span>
                </div>`;
                $("#trainTable").append(html);
            }
            $("#nrccMessages").html(response.train.nrccMessages);

        },
        complete: function(){
            if($('#temp').is(':visible')){
                $('#temp').hide();
                $('#wrapper').show();
                timeout = 60000;
            }
        },

        error : function(error){
            console.log(error)
            alert('Something went wrong');
        }

    });
  });
});
```

ajaxfile_selector.php    PHP

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
//var_dump ($_POST['train_sta']);
//echo strlen($_POST['train_sta']);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' && isset($_GET['train_stations'])) {
    // The form has been submitted, and 'train_stations' parameter is set
  $train_sta = $_GET['train_stations'];

    // Process the selected train station here
    //echo "Selected train station: " . $train_sta;
  require("OpenLDBWS.php");
  $OpenLDBWS = new OpenLDBWS("8903eb55-ca22-4d3a-83fa-d8f93956cb43");
        //var_dump($train_sta);
        //$selectedStation = "EUS";
        $response = $OpenLDBWS->GetDepBoardWithDetails(15,$train_sta); //
        //$response = $OpenLDBWS->GetDepBoardWithDetails(15,"EUS");
        //$response_station=$selectedStation;
        //print($selectedStation)
        //var_dump($response_station);
        $response = json_encode($response);
        //print_r($response);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        $trainData = array();
        $nrccMessages = '';

        // Handle NRCC messages
        if (isset($response['GetStationBoardResult']['nrccMessages']['message'])){
          $nrccMessage = $response['GetStationBoardResult']['nrccMessages']['message'];
          if (!isAssocArray($nrccMessage)){
            foreach ($nrccMessage as $msg){
              foreach ($msg as $k=>$v){
                $nrccMessages .= $v . ' ';
              }
            }
          }else{
            foreach ($response['GetStationBoardResult']['nrccMessages']['message'] as $k => $v){
              $nrccMessages .= strip_tags($v) . ' ';
            }
          }
        }
            // Get Trains
        if (isset($response['GetStationBoardResult']['trainServices']['service'])){
          $index = 0;
          foreach ($response['GetStationBoardResult']['trainServices']['service'] as $train){
            $temp = array();
            $temp['destination'] = $train['destination']['location'][0]['locationName'];
            $index = $index + 1;
                //print($index ."\n");

            $temp['platform'] = isset($train['platform']) ? $train['platform'] : '-';
            $temp['toc'] = $train['operator'];
            $temp['carriages'] = isset($train['length']) ? $train['length'] : '-';

                // Work out times
            $temp['schd'] = $train['std'];
            $temp['etd'] = $train['etd'];
            if ($train['etd'] != 'On time'){
                  // Train is late, lol.
              $schd = strtotime($train['std']);
              $etd = strtotime($train['etd']);
              $delay = ($etd - $schd) / 60;
              $temp['delay'] = $delay;

                  // Is a delay reason given?
              if (isset($train['delayReason'])){
                $temp['delayReason'] = $train['delayReason'];
              }
            }
                  // is train cancelled
            $trainCancelled = isset($train['cancelReason']);
            if ($trainCancelled){
              if ($train['cancelReason'] != ''){
                $temp['cancelReason'] = $train['cancelReason'];
              }
              $temp['cancelled'] = true;
            }
                  // Get callpoints and times
            $temp['callingPoints'] = array();
            if (!$trainCancelled){
              $trainCallingPoints = $train['subsequentCallingPoints']['callingPointList'][0]['callingPoint'];
                    // Direct train or multiple call points?
              if (isAssocArray($trainCallingPoints)){
                $temp['callingPoints'] = array(
                  'location' => $trainCallingPoints[0]['locationName'],
                  'st' => $trainCallingPoints['st'],
                  'et' => $trainCallingPoints['et']);
              }else{
                foreach ($trainCallingPoints as $callingPoints){
                  $callPoint = array(
                    'location' => $callingPoints['locationName'],
                    'st' => $callingPoints['st'],
                    'et' => $callingPoints['et']);
                  $temp['callingPoints'][] = $callPoint;
                }
              }
                        // Make a string of the calling points because I prefer PHP...
              $cpString = '';
              if (!isAssocArray($temp['callingPoints'])){
                foreach ($temp['callingPoints'] as $cp){
                  if ($cp['et'] != 'On time'){
                    $cpString .= $cp['location'] . ' (<strike>'. $cp['st'].'</strike>) ' . '('.$cp['et']  .'), ' ;
                  }else{
                    $cpString .= $cp['location'] . ' (' . $cp['st'] .'), ' ;
                  }
                }
              }else{
                $cpString = 'Calling at destination only';
              }
              $temp['callingPointsString'] = $cpString;
            }
                      // push data to array
            $trainData['train'][] = $temp;
          }
        }else{
          $trainData['train'][] = array('destination' => 'NO SERVICES', 'toc' => 'sleep', 'carriages' => '0', 'schd' => '', 'etd' => '', 'callingPointsString' => '', 'platform' => '');
        }
      }else {
                      // Handle the case where "Select a Station" is chosen
        echo "Please select a valid train station.";
        $trainData['train'][] = array('destination' => 'NSC', 'toc' => 'sleep', 'carriages' => '0', 'schd' => '', 'etd' => '', 'callingPointsString' => '', 'platform' => '');
        $trainData['nrccMessages'] = "";
        print_r(json_encode($trainData));
        exit;
      }



/*
$train_sta=$_GET['train_stations']; 

if (isset($train_sta)){
  //print_r("The variable is set");
}  else
{
  $trainData['train'][] = array('destination' => 'NSC', 'toc' => 'sleep', 'carriages' => '0', 'schd' => '', 'etd' => '', 'callingPointsString' => '', 'platform' => '');
  $trainData['nrccMessages'] = "";
  print_r(json_encode($trainData));
  exit;
}
*/ 




$trainData['nrccMessages'] = $nrccMessages;

  #//print_r($trainData); //exit;
print_r(json_encode($trainData));
exit;



function isAssocArray($arr)
{
  if (array() === $arr) return false;
  return array_keys($arr) !== range(0, count($arr) - 1);
}
?>
```

Station Selector

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(){
    alert("Submitted");
  });
});
</script>

</head>


<body style="background:#000000;">

    

    <form action="ajaxfile_selector.php" method="GET">

        <label> Train Stations</label>
        <select id="stations-list" name="train_stations">

            <option value="select">Select a Station </option>
            <option value='AAP'>Alexandra Palace </option>
            <option value='AAT'>Achanalt </option>
                        <option value='ZZT'>Lintley </option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>

</body>


</html>
```

Departure Board

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120" -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1280, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Board</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


</head>


<body onload="startTime()" style="background:#000000;">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="train_selector.js?1" type="text/javascript" ></script>

                <div class="grid-container">
                    <div class="item1">
                        <!-- <button class="button button1">Birminham New Street</button> -->
                        <button class="button button2" type="button" onClick="window.location.reload();">Refresh</button> 
                        <button class="button button2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Map</button>
                        <a href="httpxxxxxxx.html"><button class="button button2">Departures</button></a>
                        <a href="http:xxxxxxx.html"><button class="button button2">Arrivals</button></a>


                    </div>
                    <div class="item2">

                        <div id="temp"> <p style="color:white;"> Getting Data, Please wait...</p></div>
                        <div id="wrapper" style="display: none; color:white;">

                            <!--- HEADER -->
                            <div class="container header">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <h1>Departures from Selector</h1></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-1"><p style="font-size:25px">Time</p></div>
                                        <div class="col-6"><p style="font-size:25px">Destination</p></div>
                                        <div class="col-2 text-md-center"><p style="font-size:25px">Platform</p></div>
                                        <div class="col-1 text-md-center"><p style="font-size:25px">Expected</p></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!--- ROW -->
                                <div id ="trainTable" class="container border">
                                </div>

                                <!--- FOOTER -->
                                <div class="container footer">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <span id="nrccMessages" style="width:80%;"> The Ticket Vending Machines are currently out of order at this station.</span>
                                        <div class="col text-right">Time now: <span id="clock"></span></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </body>


                </html>
```

Comment: Well, you wrote `$train_sta = $train_sta=$_GET['train_stations'];`. So then...where do you _expect_ that `$_GET['train_stations']` value  will come from? It should be a parameter in the URL sent from the browser, but there is absolutely nothing in your AJAX code which tries to do that. In fact it just runs the $.ajax code when the page first loads..it does not wait for the user to select a value and submit the form. So you have got a couple of steps in the JS code to work on, before this will do anything. (And your PHP code is probably outputting a warning message about the missing GET value)

Comment: Ok, I think I get what are you saying. Probably also, it doesn't help that I have a file per code. I'll try it again as with getting the value from the URL and I'll update here. Thanks.

Comment: `it doesn't help that I have a file per code`...I don't think that makes any difference. In fact, it's usually good (from a design and maintenance point of view) to keep different functionality separate in different code files.

Comment: Anyway, first you need to make your JS code handle the "submit" event of that form. Then when the callback for that event handler runs, it needs to get the the currently selected value from the `<select` inside the form and put it in a variable. The, it needs to send an AJAX request to the server, which includes that selected value as part of the request's data.

Comment: Hi, now I'm trying to handle the form submit event with $('form').submit(function() {..}) but doesn't seem to work. In other suggestion?

Comment: That's too vague for me to tell you anything useful. Handling the form submit event like that is the correct approach to the first part of your task. It's unclear, from your description and the minimal code supplied, what "doesn't seem to work" actually means in practice. What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead? You can [edit] your question to show us a more complete example, with a better description. Then it might be possible to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thankyou. The first thing I notice is that `$('form').submit(function() {
      event.preventDefault();` needs to be `$('form').submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();` otherwise `event` will be undefined (which should have been giving you a console error), and that also means it won't prevent the form from being submitted in the normal way, and posted directly to the server.

Comment: The other obvious point is that, while you have assigned the `selectedValue` value variable, you do not actually use it for anything. You would need to send it in the AJAX request, so it reaches the PHP script. Try putting `$.ajax({ data: { "train_stations": selectedValue }, `...etc in the AJAX options so the value is submitted properly.

Comment: oh and also, `var selectedValue = $('#train_stations :selected').val();` is wrong, because 1) there is no element with `id="train_stations"`. Your select has `id="stations-list"` instead. Remember that `#` selects by `id`, not by `name` (you can read about it in the [jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and elsewhere). And 2) you don't need the `:selected` modifier. So `var selectedValue = $('#stations-list').val();` should be the right code to assign the value (but please test it yourself).